I accidentally installed GRUB on the wrong disk, what should I do?
I have two disks, lets call them A and B. A is my "main" disk, EFI partition is there, and the rest is Windows.
B has some free space as common storage, and a second partition where I install Debian.
While formatting my Windows, I accidentally formatted the whole disk A, so I lost the GRUB option in BIOS / UEFI boot menu. So I followed these steps on a live Debian USB to repair it.
I did end up repairing my initial GRUB, but I made a mistake at step 8, where I was supposed to do grub-install /dev/sda, I did  grub-install /dev/sdb instead, and update-grub. And at the heat of the moment, I closed the console, so I'm not sure what actually happened. But I'm positive I saw the usual messages, like it detected the linux kernels, Windows Boot Manager etc. No error message.
So.. did I install an unnecessary copy of GRUB somewhere in my B disk? It looks like everything is working so maybe Debian Live was smart enough to save my disk from my stupidity? How can I check if I have it installed somewhere on disk B?
Thanks
P.S.: If it makes any difference, A (/dev/nvme1n0) is an SSD and B (/dev/sda) is a SATA HDD.

As long as you are not scribbling over something important (like the boot loader for another OS you care about), it generally doesn't hurt to have grub installed on multiple disks.  Worst case, you boot the wrong disk and get an old version of grub that didn't get automatically updated.  Best case, when you accidentally format a disk or a disk fails, you can (try to?) boot grub off the other disk.
The syntax grub-install device is generally for legacy mode booting where the boot loader is written into the boot sector of the specified disk.  If you are booting EFI, grub always has to be installed in the EFI system partition (ESP) no matter where the rest of the OS is installed, and grub typically auto detects this, and might actually have ignored your device specification.
In the end, if you can successfully boot both operating systems, the fix worked, and unless you are trying to intentionally create some redundancy for next time, you've done the right thing and there's nothing more to do.

Thank you! Yeah I wasn't worried about "using the wrong grub" or something but I was worried that I corrupted my second disk, broke its headers / page table whatever its called. And I was also curious if i did install it, where is it.. Just to save those few MB's of space :D I guess I can't just install grub on a NTFS partition, so my second disk is 100% fine? Anyway, thanks

If you want to see where everything is at, run the report from Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ & https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot

Asssuming grub wrote an MBR style legacy boot record, worst case, it would have stepped on the windows boot record, which would be easy enough to put back if you needed it.  If it wrote an EFI records, that's just more files in the ESP, not a big deal there either.
